# How should students greet a group of important people? Is "Good morning sirs and madams" correct?

Tags: greetings

A group of vips will be visiting my school.

If they pop into the class, how do the students greet them?

Is "Good morning sirs and madams" correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the visitors English speakers?  What language do you use at school (for example in science lessons?) Are the visitors coming to an *English* class.

Comment: Good morning ladies and gentlemen would be the correct formal greeting.             That said, "Good morning" should suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, not in English (unless the VIPs only speak English, or you only speak English at school.) You would normally use your normal school language.

In English culture, it would be very unusual for the students to greet the visitors at all!  The students are in class and should continue with their studies. The days of "standing up when an adult enters the classroom" are long gone. The *teacher* might briefly greet the visitors, but would then return to teaching.

However it might be that there are visitors from England, are known not to speak your school language, and culturally you should greet them. In which case "Good afternoon, and welcome to the [maths] class" would not be too strange.  Avoid "sirs and madams", and avoid all speaking together like a choir.

However, ultimately it is the teacher's lesson, and so if the teacher wants you to stand and say "Good Morning to You" all together that is what you'll have to do!

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

However, the students will probably still have to greet the VIPs. 

The VIPs will step into class, then the teacher will proceed to ask the students to greet them.

Comment: @RainHeart Then by all means do as the teacher suggests - but all answering in unison, for a group over the ages of roughly of 6 or 7, sounds silly.

Comment: When addressing a large group, _ladies and gentlemen_ is better than _sirs and madams_, but "Good morning" on its own would be quite acceptable.

Comment: Hi all thanks for replying! 
Yes its all very strange but these is the culture
These are education ministers, is using ladies and gentleman ok?